# How does php_fpm_max_children_reached metrics work?

Tags: php

I'm new to php-fpm monitoring, and I'm trying to gather some metrics from a LEMP server.
I'm using the php-fpm exporter module (https://github.com/Lusitaniae/phpfpm_exporter) and particularly I would like to understand how the php_fpm_max_children_reached metrics works...

Here's a screenshot of a Grafana panel, showing the php_fpm_max_children_reached metrics from one of my servers:

[image: php_fpm_max_chidren_reached]

The graph is showing a value of 80 starting from August 9th up to 88 on August 19th.
What does it mean exactly? That the value of max children (5 for this server) has been reached 80 times constantly during the whole day of August 9th and increasingly up to August 19th?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5b01c4863fe9e4bc2702b2bbf66d292d23001a18/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_scoreboard.c#L119-L146

I took a quick look at the source code, and basically it seems to only increase, although I don't know when it updates.
If you restarted php-fpm, it would be normal to return to 0.